# Suppose $x$ is a perfect square mod $n$. If $xy \equiv 1 $ mod $n$, prove $y$ is a perfect square also.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

Here's what I have:

If $a$ is a perfect square mod $n$, then $\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $m^2 \equiv a \text{ mod } n$. We want to find some $k$ such that $k^2 \equiv b \text{ mod } n$.
\begin{align*}
ab &\equiv 1 \text{ mod } n \\
m^2b &\equiv 1 \text{ mod } n \\
b &\equiv  m^{-2} \text{ mod } n
\end{align*}

Is this satisfactory? Thanks!

Comment: How do you know $m^{-2} \mod n $ exits? What is $2^{-2}\mod 8$?

Comment: @fleablood Hm, you're right... $2^{-1}$ doesn't exist mod 8 (and so $2^{-2}$ doesn't either).

Comment: $m*(mb)=1$.  $m^2*(mb)^2=1=m^2b $.  That implies $b=(mb)^2$.  Which we can demonstrate.  $(mb)^2=m^2b^2=ab^2=(ab)b=b $.

Comment: So this is what I first did, but I didn't know if we were only interested in our square roots being less than $n$. If that's potentially allowed, then this is perfect!

Comment: I would add that since $ab=1$, then $a, b, m \in \mathbb{Z}^{\times}_{n}$

Comment: I only typed "=" because of space limitations of comments.  I assumed it'd be clear in context I meant $\equiv \mod n$.  We aren't interested in our square roots being less than n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $a \equiv m^2 \mod n$.  And we have $ab \equiv 1 \mod n$.

So $(mb)^2 \equiv m^2b^2 \equiv ab^2 \equiv (ab)b \equiv b \mod n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an improvement on fleablood's Answer but might give you some insights.... All values here are integers.

Theorem. For all non-zero $x,y$:  There exist $u,v$ such that $ux+vy=1$ iff $\gcd(x,y)=1.$ Equivalently, there exists $u$ such that $ux\equiv 1\pmod y$ iff $\gcd(x,y)=1.$

Corollary:  The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (FTA) : For all non-zero $x,y,z,$ if $y|\;xz$ and $\gcd(y,x)=1$ then $y|z.$ Because,  with $ux+vy=1$ we have $y|\;u(xz)=(ux)z=(1-vy)z=z-y(vz)\implies y|z.$

By the Theorem,  $ab\equiv 1\pmod n\implies \gcd(a,n)=1.$Now since $a-m^2\equiv 0\pmod n$ for some $m,$ we have $\gcd(m,n)=1.$

.... Because if $p|\;m$ and  $p|\;n$ then $p|\;m^2 ,$ hence  $p|\; (a-m^2) \land p|\;m^2,$ so $p|(a-m^2)+m^2=a$... But $(p|a\land p|\;n)\implies p=\pm 1 .$

Since $\gcd(m,n)=1,$ the  Theorem  implies  there exists $u$ with $um\equiv 1 \pmod n.$  Now $1\equiv u^2m^2\equiv u^2a\equiv ba \pmod n.$ So $n|\;(u^2-b)a.$

Since $\gcd(a,n)=1,$ the FTA implies $n|(u^2-b).$